# How can I click on this check box using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

I can click all of the other checkboxes on the page. But when it comes to this one, it won't allow me to click on it

The HTML code for the checkbox is:

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_wucSignInStep2_chkTC" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$wucSignInStep2$chkTC">
```

My code for clicking the text box:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[span/input[@name="checkbox checkbox-primary"]]').click()
```

I can provide the full code if required.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: eminent is not clickable at point (305, 587). Other element would receive the click

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle this issue. Please, check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `id` associated with your input field! You can use the id to find the element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_wucSignInStep2_chkTC').click()
```

That should do it.

If you are getting an `element not visible` error then you can try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_wucSignInStep2_chkTC")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The above code will make the element visible and also, put the mouse cursor over the checkbox.

Comment: when u try that I get the error: element is not clickable at point (305, 587). Other element would receive the click

Comment: Please, try the updated code. Also, feel free to mark it as accepted if it helps you to solve the issue.

Comment: @Wasi I am getting ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: @Anonymous Try waiting a few seconds before initiating the click using `time.sleep()` or even better `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.id, "id_of_the_element"))`